# Power BI Maps Can´t find City on Bing

Tags: powerbi, bing-maps, bing, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem with Bing  Map on Power BI.

In my database I have a Place called Ribeirão Gonçalves, Piauí, Brasil (City, State, Country).

I can see on the bing map website that this place does not exist on the map, and in Power BI It shows me some random area in the State Piauí, Brasil.

Also the same problem I have with Place called Terezópolis de Goiás, Goiás, Brasil, but this time the city can be found on the Bing map on the Internet but still shows wrong area.

My question is how to prevent this kind of situations? Does anyone have experience resolving such scenarios using Bing maps?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, The problem is with Bing maps, where information about places are incorrect. The problem will be solved by Bing Support Team. It will take few months.  If someone has similar issue it is good to inform them.